# NestJs Mailer Module error upon sending email

Tags: nestjs

I'm using NestJs Mailer Module, the latest stable version. You can find the documentation [here](https://nest-modules.github.io/mailer/).

I've search a solution for this error but I found nothing:

```
Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

app.module.ts:

```js
@Module({
  imports: [
    MailerModule.forRoot({
      transport: 'smtps://user@domain.com:pass@smtp.domain.com',
      defaults: {
        from:'"nest-modules" <modules@nestjs.com>',
      },
      template: {
        dir: __dirname + '/templates',
        adapter: new HandlebarsAdapter(),
        options: {
          strict: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

sending the email:

```js
        this.mailerService.sendMail({
            to: 'example@domain.com',
            subject: 'subject'
            text: 'blahblahblah'
            html: 'blahblahblah'
        }).then(() => {
            this.logger.log('Error email sent!', 'HttpExceptionFilter');
        }).catch(err => {
            this.logger.error('Error while sending error email.', err, 'HttpExceptionFilter');
        });
```

Comment: Do you have a SSL vert installed on `domain.com`?

Comment: I do have a SSL certification but it's not self signed

Comment: If I add this in my transport:```tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false }``` It does work, but I would like to know the consequences of having that feature turn off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a solution, you can use `tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false }` in your transport options.